# Exposure Compensation Blender 4 Cycles

Tags: lighting

I was wondering if blender 4 has anything similar to the exposure compensation slider that is available on UE5 at all?
With one slider you are able to bring light to the shadows without blowing the bright parts of the scene. It works very well on EU5 though.

Comment: In the compositor, RGB Curves has black and white level control

Comment: There is also the color balance node